# How to detect Apache LimitRequestLine from PHP?

Tags: php, httpd

Is there a way to get current Apache settings from a PHP script? All happens on the same server.

I have tried running `apache2ctl -DDUMP_CONFIG | grep LimitRequestLine` from within PHP. It kind of works but also wants to start Apache, bind it to a port. It sometimes fails very slowly. Also, it requires enabling the [mod_info](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_info.html) module.

Background: The JS library [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) sends very long URLs as GET requests. They are longer than the default for LimitRequestLine. Setting LimitRequestLine to a large enough value fixes this. I'd like to provide an install verification checklist that warns about potential issues after installing our PHP application.

Comment: Forget about the server configuration, and just [switch to POST requests](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/post).

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be allowing PHP to access the Apache config settings. What you can do, is have a PHP test script that will try your largest possible url length from your application. Wrap that in a try/catch and report back if it errors out, instructing how to increase this limit. This way it will work with other webservers, such as NGINX if that gets introduced into the mix.